# Hierarchy layout using sigmajs or gephi

Tags: gephi, sigma.js

Using SigmaJS or gephi toolkit, is it possible to create Hierarchy layout of the graph? I can't use linkurious.

I am currently using sigmaJS 1.2

Comment: There is no ready to use hierarchical layout in graphology, but you can compute by yourself the node's position

Comment: @logisima, I'm using 1.2 version. Is there hierarchy layout in version 1.2?

Comment: don't know ....